# Free() segfault on PIC24

Tags: c, malloc, free, pic

I have two 16-bit pointers being allocated at runtime, in order to save some long doubles to flash (using the Microchip DEE flash emulation library). The code works fine, and recalls saved values correctly, but if I use free() on the malloc()'d pointers, then the code segfaults at the next malloc() call (in another function, in another section of the code).

```
void readMicCalData(Microphone* pMicRead)
{
/* Allocate space for 2*16-bit pointers */
int16_t* tempFlashBuffer = (int16_t*)malloc(sizeof(int16_t));
int16_t* tempFlashBuffer2 = (int16_t*)malloc(sizeof(int16_t));

if ((tempFlashBuffer == NULL) || (tempFlashBuffer2 == NULL)) {
    debugMessage("\n\rHEAP> Failed to allocate memory for flash buffer!\n\r",1);
}

/* Increment through 2-byte blocks */
wc1 = RCM_MIC_CAL_START_ADDRESS;
while(wc1 < RCM_MIC_CAL_END_ADDRESS) {

    /* Init pointer to lowest 16-bits of 32-bit value e.g. 0x0D90 */
    tempFlashBuffer = (int16_t*) &pMicRead->Factor_dB[i4];

    /* Save pointer and increment to next 16-bit address e.g. 0x0D92 */
    tempFlashBuffer2 = tempFlashBuffer + 1;

    /* Read first 16-bit value */
    *tempFlashBuffer = DataEERead(wc1);

    /* Catch 0xFFFF and set to zero. Otherwise the float becomes NaN. */
    if (*tempFlashBuffer == 0xFFFF) { *tempFlashBuffer = 0; }

    /* Read next 16-bits of value */
    *tempFlashBuffer2 = DataEERead(wc1 + 1);

    if (*tempFlashBuffer2 == 0xFFFF) { *tempFlashBuffer2 = 0; }

    /* Move to next 2*16-bit block of memory */
    wc1 = wc1 + 2;

    /* Move to next saved mic. cal. frequency */
    i4++;
}

/* Free memory */
free(tempFlashBuffer);
free(tempFlashBuffer2);
}
```

Could the tempFlashBuffer2 assignment be counting as an increment? Therefore I'm not free()ing the same pointer assigned from malloc()?

If I don't free() the two pointers, the code runs fine and doesn't see any segfaults (at least not in the short term!).

Comment: Why are you mallocing at all here?  Seems like you're just reassigning them immediately if the loop is entered.

Comment: Ah. I think i've gotten myself in a spin. You are correct.

Comment: Undid edit. As the code was relevant to the responses given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointers passed to `free()` must be a pointer returned by a previous call to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`. This is not the case here as you are changing the pointer values, causing undefined behaviour. From section *7.20.3.2 The free function* of C99 standard:

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. **Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the calloc, malloc, or realloc function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc,
>   the behavior is undefined.**